# Online resources for Mathematical Modeling

Tags: mathematical-modeling, online-resources

I'm taking mathematical modeling this semester in college and usually there are resources online to read examples and see another point of view but I'm not able to find it for this class. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Mathematical Modeling is a pretty broad term. Any hints as to the genre(s) of math you may be working in? Stochastic Models? Differential Equation Models? .. etc

Comment: Right now we're covering velocity fields and such. So it's more of differential equations I guess. It's a college class so it's likely we'll cover a little of everything.

Answer (score 1):

How about this script:

http://mtm.ufsc.br/~daniel/matap/IntMatMod.pdf

or this

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~collins/Modeling/331book.pdf

Comment: Anything good to say about these links, or are they just what popped up in search results?

Comment: The second link doesn't work anymore. This is still ok: http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/MATH331/331book.pdf